# How does the factor work when the attribute mix node is set to "multiply"?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

In this practice project I am making a sphere with extruding rocks. The scale of the rocks depend on how close the selected empty object is to the sphere (as shown in the second image). In the first image, I would like to know why sliding the factor does nothing. P.S ignore the muted nodes please.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Multiply does (1-Fac)\*A + Fac\*A\*B ([src](https://github.com/sobotka/blender/blob/e648e388874a317f7846efe9ba7242a5b11a5650/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/material.c#L1550)), ie. Factor lerps between A and A\*B. So one reason Factor would do nothing is if A and A\*B are equal.

Comment: @scurest This is an answer. It should be posted as an answer, not as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what exactly you are trying to achieve. But I see that you have set mix node to multiply. In this case, you multiply dist attribute by scale. Scale is 1.

So, `dist * 1 = dist` - no changes.

Comment: I understand now, thank you